# How to check if a Client is connected to my spring boot backed server or disconnected?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, tcp, spring-websocket

I am new to Spring boot. I am currently working on a Poker app (android) and decided to use Spring Boot as Backend. Using HTTP requests and responses to handle client, I am facing difficulty when it comes to client's connectivity. cause I need to know if a player is connected to game table or not.  Can I use WebSockets to resolve this or I need to use TCP support?

Any advice is be appreciated and please help me here providing some useful resources.

Thanks

Comment: What difficutly do you have?

Comment: I can't find any way if a client is continuously connected or not when i handles request and response using HTTP and don't know how to resolve this. Please tell me what am i missing and what to do to overcome this issue

Comment: HTTP is stateless. So you are only connected when issuing a request

Comment: ya i know . thank you